# Unable to output anything using Java and Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I get [null, null] as output when I run the code. Any thoughts ?

Here is my deserialized class :

```
package TestPackage;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DeSerializeJSON {

    private String url;
    private String ip;

    public DeSerializeJSON(){}
    //I have deserialized the rest.

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return url + "," + ip;
    }
}
```

My test class is as below :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try{

            List<DeSerializeJSON> urls = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\Test\\Output.txt").getAbsoluteFile(), DeSerializeJSON[].class));
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Test\\ipUrlOutput.txt"));
            System.setOut(out);
            System.out.println(urls);
```

Comment: Show your JSON.

Comment: Here is my JSON :



    [
      {
        "items": [
          {
            "Inputs": {
              "url": "http://some.com"
            },
            "Outputs": {
              "ip": "51.70.182.125",
              "redirectipaddress": "16.150.210.199",
              "httpstatuscode": "200",
              "processes": {},
              "Steps": [],
              "Queues": {},
              "Outcomes": {
                "language": null,
                "type": null
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

Comment: First for all, the given JSON is **invalid**. There's an unexpected `;` just after `some.com`. Remove it to make it valid.

Answer (score 0):

### What's wrong

Your Java class does not match your JSON, that's why you have `null` values and you don't get any mapping exceptions because your class is annotated with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`.

### How to fix it

Consider the JSON document you posted on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45720070/unable-to-output-anything-using-java-and-jackson/45730327#comment78400070_45720070):

```json
[
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "Inputs": {
          "url": "some.com"
        },
        "Outputs": {
          "ip": "51.70.182.125",
          "redirectipaddress": "16.150.210.199",
          "httpstatuscode": "200",
          "processes": {},
          "Steps": [],
          "Queues": {},
          "Outcomes": {
            "language": null,
            "type": null
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

It requires the following classes to be parsed:

```java
public class ItemsWrapper {

    @JsonProperty("items")
    private List<Item> items;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters
}
```

```java
public class Item {

    @JsonProperty("Inputs")
    private Input input;

    @JsonProperty("Outputs")
    private Output output;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters
}
```

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Input {

    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters
}
```

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Output {

    @JsonProperty("ip")
    private String ip;

    // Default constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Then you can parse the JSON using `ObjectMapper`:

```java
String json = "[\n" +
              "  {\n" +
              "    \"items\": [\n" +
              "      {\n" +
              "        \"Inputs\": {\n" +
              "          \"url\": \"some.com\"\n" +
              "        },\n" +
              "        \"Outputs\": {\n" +
              "          \"ip\": \"51.70.182.125\",\n" +
              "          \"redirectipaddress\": \"16.150.210.199\",\n" +
              "          \"httpstatuscode\": \"200\",\n" +
              "          \"processes\": {},\n" +
              "          \"Steps\": [],\n" +
              "          \"Queues\": {},\n" +
              "          \"Outcomes\": {\n" +
              "            \"language\": null,\n" +
              "            \"type\": null\n" +
              "          }\n" +
              "        }\n" +
              "      }\n" +
              "    ]\n" +
              "  }\n" +
              "]";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ItemsWrapper[] itemsWrappers = mapper.readValue(json, ItemsWrapper[].class);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;`

```
List<DeSerializeJSON> urls = mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\Test\\Output.txt").getAbsoluteFile(), new TypeRefference<List<DeSerializeJSON>>(){});
```

Comment: I tried this, seems to be readValue method does not support TypeRefference.

Comment: What do you mean by not support?

Comment: The program shows the following error :
The method readValue(File, Class<T>) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (File, new TypeReference<List<DeSerializeJSON>>(){})

Comment: Have you imported `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference`?

Comment: First, you are suggesting a solution with _Jackson 2.x_ (`com.fasterxml.jackson` package) while the OP is using _Jackson 1.x_ (`org.codehaus.jackson` package). Second, `TypeReference` wouldn't help here: The Java class does not match the JSON the OP is trying to parse. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45730327/1426227) for details on how the Java class(es) should be designed.